# How can I trigger onblur from a ul li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-events, html-lists

I am essentially highlighting each `li` when clicked, and want to "un-highlight" the clicked `li` when clicking elsewhere or tabbing out (by effecting the `background-color` property).

This behavior would essentially be emulating `<select>` in its' highlighting behavior... I'm **not** using `select` though, because I want to nest HTML inside the listed items  --  *you **can't** do this with `<option>`*.

I'm attempting to use `onblur`, which is not working...

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id = "list">
    <li>asdf</li>
    <li>qwerty</li>
<ul>
```

...here is the CSS:

```
    #list {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

...and here is the jQuery/Javascript:

```
    function getEventTarget(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        return e.target || e.srcElement; 
    }

    function highlightSelection(selection) {
        alert("It worked!");
        $(selection).css("background-color","#FFFF00");
    }

    // this function is not being triggered:
    function removeHighlight(selection) {
        $(selection).css("background-color","none");
    }

    var ul = document.getElementById("list");

    ul.onclick = function(event) {
        var target = getEventTarget(event);
        highlightSelection(target);
    };

    // this event is not working:
    ul.onblur = function(event) {
        var target = getEventTarget(event);
        removeHighlight(target);
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using JQuery...

```
<ul id = "list">
     <li tabindex="1">asdf</li>
     <li tabindex="2">qwerty</li>
 <ul>


var ul = $("#list");
ul.on('click focus','li',function(){
    $(this)
        .css("background-color","#FFFF00")
        .siblings().css('background','');
}).on('blur','li',function(){
    $(this).css('background','');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mc4tN/2/

I wasn't sure of what effect you wanted when you tab away from a list item... It seems you would just want to leave it highlighted.  You can add focus-ability to your list items by giving them a `tabindex` attribute.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks @Bluetoft! How might I do this using `addClass` and `removeClass` instead of `css`?

Comment: Ok nevermind, I got it -- `$(this).addClass("highlighted").sibling().removeClass("highlighted");` in the contents of `ul.on('click focus'...` instead, where "highlighted" is a CSS class.

Answer (score 3):

The `li`s don't [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onblur) because they don't focus. Try with `mouseout` or `mouseleave`.

Comment: Thanks @Dek Dekku for the quick reply, is it possible to set the focus on the clicked `li`?

Comment: Now that I'm looking better, you're actually setting the listener on the `ul`.

Comment: Okay, so I almost got it -- adding the attribute `tabindex = "1"` to `ul`, or whatever integer assignment, will give `li`'s focus. *However*, this trick does *not* allow only one `li` to be highlighted at a time.

Comment: call the removeHighlight method from highlightSelection to remove highlight on the previoously selected item, them set it on the new target.

Comment: Thanks again @Dek Dekku, do you mean to access the previously assigned `target` variable from the `removeHighlight` method?

Comment: Yes, you can save it (I guess a global variable would do for now, but protecting the scope with a closure would be better) and call the method on it. Otherwise, rewrite the remove method to remove the class from all the "li"s rather than just the target: that's less efficient, but more bulletproof.